# clear external and internal cache programmatically android 6.0 above

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

how clear cache programmatically in android 6.0 above 
I use this code but its give Method invocation error because Clear_app_cache permission deprecated by google, then how to clear cache in android 6.0 above,so many app still clear cache what is the logic behind it.i use this code

```
try {
         Method freeStorageAndNotify =  context.getPackageManager().getClass()
                    .getDeclaredMethod("freeStorageAndNotify", long.class, IPackageDataObserver.class);
            long freeStorageSize = Long.MAX_VALUE;


            freeStorageAndNotify.invoke(pm, freeStorageSize, new IPackageDataObserver.Stub() {
                @Override
                public void onRemoveCompleted(String packageName, boolean succeeded) throws RemoteException {
                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(JunkFilesActivity.MSG_SYS_CACHE_CLEAN_FINISH);
                    msg.sendToTarget();
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

please give me answer. how other app still clear cache.